# How would I build a BicycleFrame in OpenModellica

Tags: openmodelica

I am trying to build a very simple bicycle frame in Openmodelica to be able to simulate accelerations on the bicycle center of gravity. It would be necessary to be able to apply accelerations or forces in vertical direction due to road unevenness on front and rear axle via a mechanics-translational connector. The horizontal distance "front axle - center of gravity - rear axle" should be predefinable. At the center of gravity, the model requires a mechanics-translational connector for the mass inertia as well as a mechanics-rotational connector for the rotational inertia.
In simplified terms, the model would be a seesaw floating in space with vertical translational input at the ends and a predefinable mass and inertia condensed at the center of gravity.

Is there something similar already available or could someone give me as much of input as possible how this could be done?

Best regards and thank you all very much.

Daniel

I've already tried to modell the frame with two ideal rolling wheels coupled to each other where the wheel radius would equal the distance "front axle - COG" and "COG - rear axle".
I've also tried to get into modelica programming, but am way to inexperienced to write the code on my own.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.